# handling laravel tokens in angular

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

So I'm building an API for a client. I decided to use Laravel 5 everything works fine except for posting data. I looked online for answers and they all said to include the laravel {{csrf_token()}} function; however, my angular app is a completely separate app in another server than the laravel API. what are some best practices for me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the csrf for that page and add basic auth (or any API authentication) instead.

Comment: that would leave all the api routes that don't need authentication vunerable